# Firefox erratic element visibility

Tags: firefox, element, visibility

I am making a website and when a user clicks a button, an element should appear.

I achieve this by doing:

```
element.style.display="block"; //to show it.
```

and:

```
element.style.display="none"; //to hide it.
```

The problem is that in Firefox the elements sometimes partially appear beneath other elements after they have become 'visible'. They then reappear when i move my mouse pointer over the area. Sometimes this newly appeared element is correctly above others but sometimes not, and it seems very random when it appears correctly and when the flaw appears. I think this has something to do with missing reflow or repaint of the DOM. I have tried changing other styles of the element at stake, hoping it will force a repain/reflow of the DOM, but to no avail.

This bug appears seemingly at random times, making it very difficult to deal with.

How do I stop this visibility problem from occurring?

Edit:
Apparently, placing a transparent element above the one at stake ameliorates the problem. Now the bug sometimes fixes itself automatically within a second of it occurring.

Comment: show some jsfiddle example.

Comment: What version of Firefox, and on what OS? What other web browsers have you tried? Do you *want* a reflow when showing/hiding the element, or is absolute positioning what you are looking for? Have you tried jQuery instead (`$(element).show()`)?

Comment: The OS is LUbuntu 13.04 and the browser is Firefox 26. I have tested it in Chrome, Chromium and Opera as well and the problem does not seem to exist there. Yes it's like the browser simply forgets to repaint parts of the element so if i could force a reflow then that may well solve it. I would really like to not include jquery in this assignment as this would be the only thing that module does. I'm not sure if i understand 'or is absolute positioning what you are looking for'.

Comment: Could this be related to z-indexes? I ran into an issue recently with safari where a scrolling overlapping div would disappear mid scroll then reappear in (what appeared to be) the wrong stacking order. Adding `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` reset the z-index stacking order and everything worked as expected.  I guess the point is you might look into z-index issues and verify that everything is where it should be.  There's an excellent article here about z-indexes, stacking order and the implications.  http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: the same z-index solved in my case. i put a tool tip like div show hide on mouse over and mouse out

Comment: This question is useless without any example. Users asking, OP doesn't respond... we can only speculate what's happening here. Useless question, voting to close.

Comment: not useless if somebody is having a problem with this description and then sees what i did to solve it. It took me a while to come to this solution. I dont know if its related to z-indexes and its too much work making a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved the problem was to define the div causing the erratic visibility after the onload event.